# Kraken API with VB Net "invalid key"

Tags: c#, vb.net, cryptography

I am trying to convert the C# code here(In particular, the "QueryPrivate" function):
https://bitbucket.org/arrivets/krakenapi/src/cff138b017c38efde2db1a080fb765790a6d04c8/KrakenClient/KrakenClient.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

To working VB Net code. I keep getting an "invalid key" response. Here is the code I've come up with:

```
Private Function QueryPrivate(a_sMethod As String, Optional props As String = Nothing) As String
        ' generate a 64 bit nonce using a timestamp at tick resolution
        _url = "https://api.kraken.com"
        _version = 0
        _key = "Key Here"
        _secret = "Secret Here"

        _rateGate = New RateGate(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        Dim nonce As Int64 = DateTime.Now.Ticks
        props = Convert.ToString("nonce=" + nonce.ToString()) & props


        Dim path As String = String.Format("/{0}/private/{1}", _version, a_sMethod)
        Dim address As String = _url & path
        Dim webRequest__1 As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(address), HttpWebRequest)
        webRequest__1.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        webRequest__1.Method = "POST"
        webRequest__1.Headers.Add("API-Key", _key)


        Dim base64DecodedSecred As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(_secret)

        Dim np = nonce.ToString() + Convert.ToChar(0) + props

        Dim pathBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(path)
        Dim hash256Bytes = sha256_hash(np)
        Dim z = New Byte(pathBytes.Count() + (hash256Bytes.Count() - 1)) {}
        pathBytes.CopyTo(z, 0)
        hash256Bytes.CopyTo(z, pathBytes.Count())

        Dim signature = getHash(base64DecodedSecred, z)

        webRequest__1.Headers.Add("API-Sign", Convert.ToBase64String(signature))

        If props IsNot Nothing Then

            Using writer = New StreamWriter(webRequest__1.GetRequestStream())
                writer.Write(props)
            End Using
        End If

        'Make the request
        Try
            'Wait for RateGate
            _rateGate.WaitToProceed()

            Using webResponse As WebResponse = webRequest__1.GetResponse()
                Using str As Stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream()
                    Using sr As New StreamReader(str)
                        Dim responseContent3 As String = sr.ReadToEnd
                        Return responseContent3
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch wex As WebException
            Using response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(wex.Response, HttpWebResponse)
                Using str As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                    Using sr As New StreamReader(str)
                        Dim responseContent3 As String = sr.ReadToEnd
                        Return responseContent3
                    End Using
                End Using

            End Using
        End Try
    End Function
    Private Function sha256_hash(value As [String]) As Byte()
        Using hash As SHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create()
            Dim enc As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8

            Dim result As [Byte]() = hash.ComputeHash(enc.GetBytes(value))

            Return result
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function getHash(keyByte As Byte(), messageBytes As Byte()) As Byte()
        Using hmacsha512 = New HMACSHA512(keyByte)

            Dim result As [Byte]() = hmacsha512.ComputeHash(messageBytes)


            Return result
        End Using
    End Function
```

I cannot figure out why this keeps returning an invalid key, other than the way I'm encoding the key must be different than how it is done in C#

Comment: This is wrong: `props = Convert.ToString("nonce=" + nonce.ToString()) & props`. Use & to combine strings in VB not +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues in your code where you combine strings and chars together.

To concatenate strings in VB use `&` instead of '+'

You are also using several help functions for hashing which could also have problems.

Your best bet is to launch the program in both C# and VB at the same time and step through each line of code until you find out where there is a difference between the two.

Comment: Good catch. However, I tried changing all of the '+' signs to '&' and I still return "invalid key". I don't think I can just step through it and find the issue, because it has to do with whatever way I'm sending the key

Comment: You can still step through line by line and make sure that each variable is the same at each step. You'll find in one or more lines there is something that doesn't match the C# version.

Comment: Ah alright I'll try that. It has to be something stupid that I did

Comment: Ok I found 2 issues. One I resolved which was changing the C# code which was  `code` var np = nonce + Convert.ToChar(0) + postData;, to the VBnet equivalent `code`Dim np = nonce.ToString() & postData

Now I can't figure out this portion. C# `code` var z = new byte[pathBytes.Count() + hash256Bytes.Count()]; gives me a length of 50, and the vbnet `code` Dim z = New Byte(pathBytes.Count() & (hash256Bytes.Count() - 1)) {} gives me a length of 1832. Any ideas here?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no magic bullet converting from one language to another besides comparing line by line the variables in your program to the working program. That conversion looks like it was done by developer fusion. Have you tried Telerik's converter?

Comment: Yes that is what I used. var z = new byte[pathBytes.Count() + hash256Bytes.Count()]; converts to Dim z = New Byte(pathBytes.Count() + (hash256Bytes.Count() - 1)) {} however that returns the wrong byte length

Comment: As soon as I typed that I realized my mistake lol I added the '&' before, when indeed that section of code was supposed to be '+'. Dim z = New Byte(pathBytes.Count() + (hash256Bytes.Count() - 1)) {} is correct as is.  Thanks for the help I got it working!

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say that line of code looked wrong at first but it is correct. In VB you need to subtract 1. Good to hear you are all set.